# WPF exit event routing

Tags: wpf, events, routes

My question is: will the Application.Exit event tunnel to any children of the application? Like a View UserControl - can I subscribe for it?

Why I ask this is that my business logic is not available from the Application class and I want to process a Logout on exit.

Comment: How can I offer a bounty for my own question? I could offer like 200 points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tunnelling only applies to routed events in the UI.  However, you can access the static instance of the application (`Application.Current`) and attach a handler to its exit event from anywhere in your code...